# HQL .setParameter inside single quotes

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql

I have an HQL query:

```
select
  date_trunc('day', s.date),
  sum(s.price)
from Sale as s
group by date_trunc('day', s.date)
```

Now I try to parametrize partition interval ('day'):

```
String interval = "'month'"
createQuery("select date_trunc(:partitionBy, s.date) from Sale as s group by date_trunc(:partitionBy, s.date)")
.setParameter("seller", seller)
.setParameter("partitionBy", interval)
```

It doesn't work.

How I can pass a String parameter inside a single quotes?

I use PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: I think you don't need a single quote since hibernate will add it for you if corresponding column in database table is of char

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
String interval = "month";
...
date_trunc('''' || :partitionBy || '''', s.date)
```

(two single quotes is an escape sequence for a single quote, || is a concatenation operator)

But I think you don't need single quotes here at all.

Comment: why do you have 4 quoted here? shouldn't it be 3?